# What's the largest number?

Tags: numerical-methods

I have problems with the problem: What's the largest number?

\begin{align}
  &60^{\frac{1}{3}} \mbox{ or } 2 + 7^{\frac{1}{3}}&
\end{align}

I tried using factorization, but I didn't get a good result and I dislike using an estimate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Compare the cubes of your numbers, which are $60$ and 
$$(2+7^{1/3})^3=8+3\cdot2^2\cdot 7^{1/3}+3\cdot 2\cdot 7^{2/3}+7=15+12\cdot 7^{1/3}+6\cdot 7^{2/3}.$$ Now $7^{1/3}<44/23$...

Comment: That is still quite painful though, unfortunately.

Comment: The cubes are within 0.1 of each other, so something more probably needs to be said about how to deal with the two remaining cube roots. It would be the perfect tip if the problem said $63^{1/3}$, though!

Comment: @dinoboy, you should probably adapt your definition of *painful* to something more realistic!

Answer (score 2):

$$
(2+\root3\of7)^3<(2+\root3\of7)^3+(2-\root3\of7)^3=16+12\root3\of{49}.
$$
Here
$$
16+12\root3\of{49}<60\Leftrightarrow\root3\of{49}<\frac{11}3.
$$
The last inequality holds because both sides are positive and cubing gives a true inequality
$$
49\cdot27=1323<1331=11^3.
$$

Comment: Adding a small quantity to one side simplified it somewhat, but didn't affect the conclusion, so it worked. I was very fortunate in that sense (or the problem was designed with such a trick in mind).

Comment: The trick is justified / motivated because you know that $(2+\sqrt[3]{7})^3$ is not an integer, while 60 is.

Comment: @Calvin: Yeah, but I would have felt more certain about success (I'm sure you would have too), if I were dealing with an algebraic number of degree two. Adding a conjugate and all that. Here there were no small conjgates around, but simplification was still to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Cube both sides of the inequality.

Comment: I am not following this hint, can you provide more detail as to what you meant?